# How to use a loop on a named range

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am getting a

> Run-time error '424'

with my For . . . Next loop.

I have created a time sheet for my work where I only need to enter start and finish times. Then, depending on the day of the week it calculates which hours are worked as Monday to Friday (MF), Saturday-Sunday (SS) or a public holiday (PH). There is a column at the start with a check box for each employee to indicate if they worked as a supervisor or not. (This is important to set pay rates and also charge rates when invoicing. Supervisors are charged a flat rate for every day except public holidays.) The check boxes are linked to the cell underneath them to show true/false depending on whether checked or not.

I am trying to total up the type of hours worked on each day of the week. The column with the check boxes in is a named range (ChargeSuper) on the worksheet. What I need to do for each employee is see if the checkbox is true or false and then add up the times for all employees on each day of the week. But I am getting a runtime error at the start of the loop.

This is what I have written so far:

```
Dim ChargeSuper As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range

'
    Dim SupHrs As Single
    Dim SupPH As Single
    Dim StdMF As Single
    Dim StdSS As Single
    Dim StdPH As Single
'
    For i = 1 To 7
' Set hours to 0
    SupHrs = 0
    SupPH = 0
    StdMF = 0
    StdSS = 0
    StdPH = 0
    r = 2 + i
'
    For Each MyCell In ChargeSuper
        If MyCell = False Then
            StdMF = StdMF + MyCell.Offset(r, 1).Value
            StdSS = StdSS + MyCell.Offset(r, 2).Value
            StdPH = StdPH + MyCell.Offset(r, 3).Value
        Else
            SupHrs = SupHrs + MyCell.Offset(r, 1).Value
            SupHrs = SupHrs + MyCell.Offset(r, 2).Value
            SupPH = SupPH + MyCell.Offset(r, 3).Value
        End If
    Next MyCell
```

The error occurs at the line "For Each MyCell in ChargeSuper". What I want is for it to check each cell with the check box. If it is not checked (False) then add the hours as standard staff. If it is checked then add them as a supervisor.

I have not written VBA for a long time, but this is above what I knew back then too. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set that named range, You only declared that, but not set.

Comment: You `Dim ChargeSuper as Range` but you never `Set` it to any value.